# Emacs occasionally opens file with blank screen

Tags: osx

I have the following issue with emacs (version 27.2 and I am on a Mac running os 12 Monterey).  Occasionally when I open a file which already exists the emacs buffer shows me a blank screen.  This has happened with .py files and .tex files --- I haven't yet recreated it with other extensions.  If I then kill the buffer and go to my terminal and interact with the file in any way there (e.g. typing "more filename" to see its contents), after that emacs seems to have no trouble opening the file.

So I know how to work around this issue, but I'd love to know why it is happening and get it to stop if possible.

Edit:  I did just notice that emacs is giving me the error message "File exists but cannot be read" on first attempt of opening the file.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mistyping something? Are you sure your current directory in emasc is the one where the file is located?

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue.  This happens when I open a file using C-x C-f and I typically use TAB to complete the name.  I did just notice that I am getting an error message "File exists but cannot be opened" which I hadn't noticed (it would get replaced with a warning that offsets couldn't be guessed)